# controls in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a textbox array using that i create 20 text boxes in runtime,
   i need to get the focus if a particular text box(if i press downarrow
   in keyboard how to get the key down of a particular text box it can be 
   3rd text box).

Comment: What does this have to do with remoting?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an Event-Handler to your KeyDown-Event:

```
yourTextboxArray[x].KeyDown += new KeyDownEventHandler(yourMethodHere);
```

The event has two parameters, `sender (Object)` and `e (KeyDownEventArgs)`. You can use the `sender` to determine what Textbox has send the KeyDown.

```
Textbox txb_sender = sender as Textbox;
if(txb_sender != null)
      // do something here with it
```